# State error with showing a dialog control

Tags: xpages, state, xpages-extlib

I'm using the following:

```
Domino Release 9.0.1FP4HF71,
ExtensionLibrary v16, 
ApplicationLayout control with 'bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration',
theme: 'Bootstrap3.2.0_flat'
```

In the configuration markup of application layout control I have a basicLeafNode for Login dialog window.

```
<xe:this.bannerUtilityLinks>
    <xe:basicLeafNode label="Login" submitValue="Login">
        <xe:this.onClick><![CDATA[XSP.openDialog("#{id:dialogLogin}");]]></xe:this.onClick>
    </xe:basicLeafNode>
</xe:this.bannerUtilityLinks>
```

Here is markup with properties for my loginDialog:

```
<xe:dialog id="dialogLogin" title="Sign In" preventCache="true"
    preload="true" keepComponents="false" partialRefresh="true"
    extractContent="true">
    ...
</xe:dialog>
```

Mostly when I click the `Login` link I got this dialog window:

[normal login dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYYdd.jpg)

It works fine. 
The problem appears when I open this page later after session timeout expires (or something else goes wrong).
First, application layout control renders Utility Links list for "previously logged-in" user (with username and `Logout`) and then it immediatly "refreshed" itself with links for Anonymous user (`Login` and `Sign up`).

If I click `Login` now then I'll get an empty dialog with header only:

[login dialog with empty content part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYkAP.jpg)

and a following message in server console:

```
HTTP JVM: WARNING: CLFAD####W: State data not available for /index because no control tree was found in the cache.
```

I've tried to change properties for dialogLogin control with different values, changed page's `viewState` property to `nostate` and encreased `xsp.application.timeout` and `xsp.session.timeout` properties.
But it looks like I have no influence here.

After the full page refresh my dialog works fine again.

Any suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `viewState="nostate"` makes the page stateless, so no component tree is ever stored. If the page is left to timeout, dialog and partial refreshes will fail, that's correct behaviour.

Increasing the timeouts may work, but if someone just closes the browser, then the server doesn't know, so the component trees will remain stored until the timeout has elapsed.

Keep Session Alive component may give you what you want. But XPages is still running on top of HTTP. If the HTTP session times out, you still have a problem.

Comment: How do we identify the HTTP session is timed out? Is there any way that if HTTP session is timed out then inform user to login again or re-direct them to login page.

Comment: Paul, is there a way to rebuild dialog again in a single call without need to refresh the page? Perhaps, it can be done in some phase of jsf lifecycle, but I'm not enough experienced with that. Can you tell who prints the "State data not available" message? Is it code of application layout control?

Comment: @PrashantArkal not with XPages, unless the application is Anonymous access. Otherwise any call will prompt for authentication via HTTP to access the XPage, before it can create a component tree for that XPage.

Comment: @EvgeniyFedorenko Rebuild the dialog from what? The "State data not available" will be triggered from the core XPages runtime, when an exception is thrown in the RESTORE VIEW phase. If you can work out how to check for a component tree, you may be able to check in the before event of the RESTORE View phase in a Phase Listener, and re-route. I'm not aware of anyone who's tried it.